# Этимология слова "внезапно"

Tags: этимология

Внезапно — вне чего? Или как тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Происходит от праслав. формы, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. запа, заапа «надежда, ожидание», вънезапу «вдруг», ст.-слав. въ незаѣпѫ (Зогр.), въ незаІАпѫ (Остром.), вънезаапѫ (Зогр., Мар., Ассем.), русск.-церк.-слав. без запа, без заІАпа «неожиданно», невъзапъ, невъзаапъ — то же, изнезапа, изнезапу, изнезапы — то же, незаІАпъ «неожиданность», др.-чешск. japati, jápati «наблюдать», nedojiepie «неожиданно», z japna «быстро», в.-луж. nezjapki «нечаянно», чешск., словацк. nejapný «неуклюжий, неловкий, нелепый», сюда же русск.-церк.-слав. заІАпѣти (ὑφορᾶσθαι, заІАпие (μηχανή. Представленное здесь *ар-сравнивают с лат. opīnor «полагаю, воображаю», opīnio «мнение», opto, optāre «желать», optio «свободное волеизъявление, выбор», inopīnus «неожиданный, внезапный», necopīnus — то же. Сомнительна связь с греч. ἐξαπίνης «внезапно». Сравнивают также с уповать, ст.-слав. оупъвати «надеяться, полагаться». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Из викисловаря.